# Polymorphism in Java - can I set an object to a specific type?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I am a programmer who is getting to grasps with polymorphism after a long break and I was wondering if the following is possible. Say I had a super class in which there were some instance variables A, B and C. In all subclasses A and B are strings and behave as such in all subclasses however in all of the subclasses, the type of C may depend on the state of the subclass. I was wondering if it is possible to set C as type 'Object' in the superclass and then specify its type in each subclass using wrapper classes. e.g

```
public class SuperClass {
    String A;
    String B;
    Object C;

    public SuperClass(){}
    }
}
public class SubClassA extends SuperClass {

    public SubClassA () {
        C = new String(); //notice this type is different from its type in the next class
    }

}

public class SubClassB extends SuperClass {

    public SubClassB () {
        C = new Integer();
    }
}
```

your thoughts would be appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: Did you try compiling and running your code?

Comment: This isn't poly-anything. You're setting `C` to an object in `SubClassA`, and you're setting `C` to an object in `SubClassB`. As I understand it, polymorphism is when the behavior of a function changes necessarily in a sub-class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: I get errors in eclipse before this even runs, namely the variable C cannot be resolved to a variable which is as I understand meaning it doesn't have type. Is it actually possible to achieve this? And If so where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Lukeg101 Eclipse error messages sometimes can be misleading.  I compiled with javac, and the extra '}' character in SuperClass was easy enough to find.  Your code compiled after I fixed that.

Comment: Thanks haha, this was only an example of what I wanted to acheive, however when I call new Integer() I get the error 'the constructor Integer() is undefined', I have imported java.util.* but there is no change. Please advise

Comment: RTM.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: "constructor Integer() is undefined". That's a pretty clear error message. The is no zero-parameter constructor in integer. You can't create an Integer without an *number*.

Answer (score 0):

No.  "Set an object to a specific type" does not mean anything.  In fact, "Set an object." does not mean anything.

A, B, and C in your example are not objects, they are variables.  There are three kinds of variable in Java; primitives (e.g, int, boolean, double), array reference variables, and object reference variables.  A, B, and C are object reference variables.  That means, A, B, and C each hold the *identity* of some object.

Initially, they all hold `null` which is a special object reference that means "no object."

Your subclass constructors each create a new object, and store its identity in C.

Objects have types which can be known at run-time, and variables have types which are only known at compile time.  The compiler will reject your code if it can prove that you assign the identity of some object to an object reference variable with an incompatible type.

The type of variable C, Object, is compatible with any object.  You can assign a String reference to it, or you can assign an Integer reference to it, or you can assign a ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory reference to it.  The downside, is that the compiler will only let you perform operations through C that can be performed on every type of object.  The compiler won't allow you to call C.toUpperCase()---not even if it holds a reference to an actual String object.---because you have explicitly declared that C *may* hold references to things that are *not* Strings.

---

I would not write the code that you wrote, but it's hard to say what I would write instead, because your example doesn't actually *do* anything.  You'll get better answers in this forum if you ask questions about how to solve actual problems.

Comment: P.S.:  Nobody starts variable names with upper-case letters anymore.  Not in any language.  That style went out with the 029 keypunch.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Understand, first and foremost, the difference between an *object* and a *reference*.  An *object* is something that you create with `new` and it has a specific type (class) that is fixed from the moment it's created.  A *reference* is a "pointer" to an object.

A single reference can point to different types of objects at different times, so long as the declared type of the reference is the class of the object *or its superclass*.  `Object` is the superclass of all objects (including arrays, but not "scalars" like `int`, `char`, `float`, etc) and hence a reference declared with type `Object` can point to any object.

Of course, if you have a reference declared as `Object` then even if you (supposedly) know what's in it, the compiler and JVM haven't a clue.  So you need to "cast" the reference to the appropriate type before you can use it.  Eg, knowing that you previously stored a pointer to a `String` object into `C`, you might do:

```
String castFromC = (String)C;
Char charFromC = castFromC.charAt(5);
```

If it turns out that `C` is not a String but is instead an Integer, then the `(String)` "cast" operation will fail at runtime with a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your concern, your posted code looks OK to me. However, it will force you to cast C to a specific type for it to be "operable" since you just declared the object reference `C` as just a "reference pointing to an `Object` type of Java object".

To avoid the ugly typecasting, you can generify your superclass like this

```
class SuperClass<T> {
    String A;
    String B;
    T C;

    public SuperClass(){}
}
```

And in your subclasses, you can use it like this

```
class SubClassA extends SuperClass<String> {

    public SubClassA () {
        C = new String();
    }
}

class SubClassB extends SuperClass<Integer> {

    public SubClassB () {
        C = new Integer(0);
    }
}
```

Also, it is a convention that your instance variables should have a meaningful name starting with lowercase, declared private, and exposed to other classes with public getters and setters.